# Competing internal transfer offers

Tags: internal-transfer

I have interviewed for an internal transfer in my company, and have been told that the hiring manager has submitted my information to the compensation department and we are all just waiting for the details of the offer they plan to make me.

In the meantime, I have been contacted by a contact in another department, asking if I'd be interested in her position, as she will soon be promoted elsewhere in the company.

Can I explore the second opportunity while waiting to officially hear about the first?

Should I disclose the situation to all parties?

Comment: I agree with Joe.  Check with HR

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can explore the second opportunity. This is especially true when your current job is in jeopardy.

When the first position makes you a formal offer, they will ask you to drop any other internal positions you are looking at, or any positions you are being considered for, when you accept their offer. They do this because they don't want you to accept the offer, then go with the a second internal position that make an offer the next day.

There is no guarantee that the offer for the first position will be what you want. In the past I have rejected formal offers for various internal transfers because despite what I was told in the application process and the interview:

- the new position was a pay cut;
- the work location was 30 miles away;
- the contract was only good for 60 days;
- I would have to work nights for the first year;
- they would have to wait for the new contract to be awarded in a few months.

Just like applying for external options, you want to keep your options open. Expect that they can see any internal applications, and be honest about them; unless of course your current boss knows nothing about your looking for a new position.